# Troubleshooting "traps: proces_name[pid] general protection" memory issue on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, troubleshooting, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to troubleshoot a memory issue on one of my servers. Some time ago a daemon my company is developing crashed with segmentation errors. All would be somewhat fine, but seconds later other services (Nginx, postgress, syslog, ssh) also started crashing, also with segmentation errors. This looks to me like either environmental/HW issue or kernel/system library bug. Is there something I can do besides a long term memtest or migrating to another system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly were the issues here because the project was abandoned, but the lesson I learned from this was that when it comes to memory issues you cannot trust OOM killer to do its job properly.